# Replace PHP:FunctionName with the PHP function return

Tags: php, string, function, replace

So what I've got is a page stored in a database that has some content then the PHP function load_users then some more content. What I need to do is search the string retrieved from the database for PHP:FunctionName(Different on everypage) and then replace it with the functions return.

Lets say in the database I have

```
    <h1>Online Users</h1>
    PHP:LoadOnline
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah</p>
```

I want to be able to search for that PHP: and get the function name beside it and then execute it and display the results. Is this possible or am I gonna have to figure something else out?

Comment: I have this: 
        echo str_replace('PHP:load_users',load_users(),$pageString);
But that requires that I put in what function to look for and it for some reason runs the function above the other content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

```
function printSomeText()
    {
    echo 'text';
    }

$template = "
 <h1>Online Users</h1>
    PHP:printSomeText sdf
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah</p>";

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/PHP\:([^\s]*)/', function ($matches)
        {
        $function = $matches[1];
        ob_start();
        $function();
        $return = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $return;
        }, $template
);
```

This way would be 'lazy' enough.

Comment: The problem with that is I have to specify exactly what function I'm looking for which makes things difficult because I want the person editing pages to just be able to type PHP:WhateverFunction and it work plus that still doesn't explain why the functions return displays before any of the other content even though its in the middle of the content

Comment: Please specify your functions for examples.

Comment: Figured out why it was displaying incorrectly so thats solved. Basically lets say one function returns hi and another returns hello I want the client to be able to type PHP:hi and it run the function that returns hi but if they type PHP:hello it run the function that returns hello